# How to calculate Newey West t-statistic in SAS 9.2?

Tags: sas

I need to run Newey West t statistics in SAS 9.2. I already run regression, White's test, Breusch Godfrey test and Jarque-Bera normality test.
Regression is simple. Number of observations = 522 
Depended variable name: rtest 1
Independent variable name: rtest 2
Data are time series data.

I found somewhere that i should start with:

```
PROC model;
PARMS B0 B1;
rtest1=B0+B1*rtest2;
```

I do not understand this part:

```
FIT rtest1/GMM Kernel=(BART,1,0.605);
RUN;
```

How to get numbers in parenthesis. What is meaning of those numbers?
What does command `FIT` do to data?
Do I need to add more commands?

Comment: It's in [the manual](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_model_sect035.htm): look below Figure 18.21.

Comment: @whuber (+1) That is *the* response, isn't it?

Comment: @chl A *good* response would explain what the Bartlett kernel is and perhaps address the final question about adding more commands.  I put this in as a comment really hoping it would result in an improved, more specific question.

Comment: @whuber That's a fair point, indeed.

Answer (score 3):

By testing for normality and running more than one test you are not preserving the operating characteristics of the "test".  In other words, type I error and confidence interval coverage will be disturbed.  A better approach would be to just use a parametric or semi-parametric method and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

To perform Newey-West standard error correction, PROC MODEL is run again specifying the GMM estimation method in the FIT statement. KERNEL=(BART, 5, 0) is also specified which requests the Bartlett kernel with a lag length of 4. The VARDEF=n option is specified to be consistent with the original Newey-West formula.

```
 proc model data=two;
        ...
         fit r_invest / gmm kernel=(bart,5,0) vardef=n;
         run;
```

here is the reference : http://support.sas.com/kb/40/098.html